# Forgetful Functor ($\mathbb{Z}$-Alg to Ab) and Limits/Colimits

Tags: category-theory

Working through homework problems so I would appreciate just a small nudge in the right direction. Note: all rings are commutative with unit.

I showed that pullbacks for Ab and $\mathbb{Z}$-Alg are just $[(a,b) \in A \times_{C} B: f(a) = g(b)]$, where $f: A \to C$ and $g: B \to C$. So, by dropping the ring structure via the forgetful functor, we have that pullbacks are preserved by the forgetful functor. Is this correct?

For pushouts, I am slightly stuck. In the category Ab, pushouts are simply $A \oplus B$ modded by the group generated by $\langle f(c), -g(c)\rangle $, where $f: C \to A$ and $g: C \to B$. However, in $\mathbb{Z}$-Alg, the pushout is just $A \otimes_{C} B$. My initial guess is that they are not the same since tensor products are generally much larger than direct sums. Am I heading in the right direction?

Comment: The [tag:proof-verification] tag is for when you already have a proof. Since you believe this is false, all you need to prove it is a counterexample, so simply calculated some examples. If your guess is right, it shouldn't take too much time to find a counterexample.

Comment: The forgetful functor is left adjoint so it preserves colimits. However, pullbacks are not colimits so I am starting to believe I have everything completely wrong.

Comment: The forgetful functor is left adjoint ? What would be its right adjoint ?

Comment: @YunusSyed The forgetful functor is right adjoint, with it's left adjoint being the free $\mathbb Z$-algebra generated by the abelian group (the tensor algebra). So, indeed, forgetful functor should preserve limits (including pullbacks), but not colimits in general.

Comment: You're right. Just look at any nontrivial tensor product of rings.